# Automatic correct the point location using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I wanted to automatically correct the actual points based on the design points.
In the picture below the transparent points are the design points and the grey were the actual points.

Could someone suggest a script or tool in QGIS that I may achieve this?

[image]

Comment: This question lacks clarity, like what links actual points and design points? is it closest spatially that you want to "correct" or do design and actual points have pairs of unique ids? ... The clearer the question the easier and faster it will be answered.

Comment: Have you tried [Snap geometries to layer](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgissnapgeometries)?

Comment: @LouisCottereau the design points have IDs and coordinates. The actual points were from a drilling machine, for which needs to be corrected.

Comment: Remember to update the question with the details you've mentioned in the comments

Answer (score 2):

Store the geometries of the "design points" in a dictionary, update geometries of the "actual points" with ids in it.

```
#Move actual to design by matching ids

actual = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("actual")[0]
design = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("design")[0]

actual_idfield = "actualid" #Name of the id field in actual layer, the one to match points by in design layer
design_idfield = "designid" #And the name in design layer

#Create a dictionary with design ids as keys and their geometries as values
designgeoms = {f[design_idfield]:f.geometry() for f in design.getFeatures()}
#{1: <QgsGeometry: Point (619112.59352650737855583 7448225.37029889225959778)>, 2: <QgsGeometry: Point (619948.5601430693641305 7447807.38699061144143343)>, ...}

newgeometries = {} #A dictionary to store feature ids of acutal features as id, and new geometries as keys
for f in actual.getFeatures():
    if f[actual_idfield] in designgeoms: #If there is a matching id in the designgeoms
        newgeometries[f.id()] = designgeoms[f[actual_idfield]] #Store the new geometry in newgeometries dict

#newgeometries is now:
#{0: <QgsGeometry: Point (619016.13583998091053218 7449077.41319654230028391)>, 1: <QgsGeometry: Point (619112.59352650737855583 7448225.37029889225959778)>, 3: <QgsGeometry: Point (620334.39088917488697916 7448273.59914215561002493)>, 4: <QgsGeometry: Point (619948.5601430693641305 7447807.38699061144143343)>}

actual.dataProvider().changeGeometryValues(newgeometries)
```

[image]

Comment: A good trick with the `changeGeometryValues` !